# Sync database configurations from php file to node.js file

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, bash

I want to manage my database connections more efficiently.

As of now I have a `database.php` file in my php code repo which is getting changed very frequently (once in a day).

I am looking for an efficient solution to manage my node `database.js` file so that when ever some IP or user name gets changed in `database.php`, that should also get reflected in`database.js` file.

The node server should restart when `database.js` is updated, at that time.

Currently I am managing this with a Bash script that runs every 10 minutes.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can create an Api to sync. When there is a change in DB(PHP) through the API tells Node the single record modified or to update the entire DB datas

Comment: but this won't restart my node server.

Comment: Why restart the server?  Can't you  reload only the Db ?